# Stacked Chart with the wrong type of data with Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am in a trouble that the stacked chart in the left side runs well with JSFiddle. However, that code did not run with my ASP.NET. Here are the error and code. Please let me know how to address this problem.

> You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView×

[image: 1]

---

### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/pu5wbgpv/3/

```
<div id="div_id"></div>
```

---

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js'>
</script><script type=text/javascript>
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages:['bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(){
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Month','Target Shipment','Actual Shipment'],['JAN',1053355,482899],['FEB',322087,468206],]);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
var options = {  };
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div_id'));
chart.draw(view, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would presume that the data you are passing in to `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()` is correct in your Fiddle but incorrect in your actual application. If you take the data in your app and post in in your fiddle - what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The data that was in my database. I could use that for the right side chart and it run very well. However, it made the error as my thread when I used `google charts bar`. Then, it tried to use that data and pass it to the JSFiddle and it worked with JSFiddle...